# Splitting profit into members

Tags: project-team, small-projects

My colleagues (2 friends of mine (Financial & International Management students) and I (Full stack JEE Developer) 
developed a prototype of a project we want to pitch soon.

## Background

Initially we splitted the Project (Me the tech geek, programming and stuff) and they had the Ideas and were like my customers giving me tasks.

## Situation

However I'm very unsatisfied with the profit sharing. Their suggestion was everybody would receive 1/3 of the profit.

But in the end I was the one developing it 100%.

They haven't assisted me in programming (they also have no experience).

## Question(s)

- How would you guys react to that? Am I overreacting?
- Are there any other possible solutions than this 1/3 share?

## Edit

This was a personal project, no company involved.

Comment: This post is about business structures and profit sharing, rather than about the practice or profession of project management.

Comment: You might look at [Slicing Pie](https://www.amazon.com/Slicing-Pie-Handbook-Perfectly-Bootstrapped-ebook/dp/B01LZJWFXH) for a better way to look at equity splits.

Comment: Be honest. Would you have come up with the idea on your own? Would you have had the necessary domain knowledge to do it the way your prospective customers would want it? Do you have the business skills to turn it into a company / product? Having an idea without the ability to execute it is just as worthless as having the ability to execute an idea without having one that's worth executing.

Answer (score 2):

I hope your two partners never see this post.  There's so much more to make a product successful in a fickle market than building product...especially a prototype.  There are a host of other knowledge and skill sets required to move a product through its natural lifecycle and to yield a profit, that you likely do not have or that they have more than you or that maybe three of you don't have and you'll need to hire.

My best advice to you is to temper your grandiose view of your talents and give more credence to your partners' contributions to the success of your product, even if they won't step in until later in the lifecycle.  In fact, they'll likely think the same of your contribution when their tempo skyrockets and you slow down.

And lastly, and most importantly, you guys are supposed to be friends.  That's far more valuable than an increase in profit share.  If you don't recognize that, then your two friends need a new friend.

Comment: I understand your point, however I think I have way more contacts to actually spread the prototype. 
I just don't think advertising(+ getting investors) is worth 1/3, I could do that myself.

Comment: Your view is not atypical, in my experience.  I cannot tell you how many conversations in which I have engaged with some type of IT technologist who minimized or dismissed the many other non technical skill sets on any project with an IT component.  The techno-centricity is overwhelming...and incorrect in most, if not all cases.  If you think you're right, kick them to the curb.  Good luck.